# System of differential equations using Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Using Laplace transform, solve the system:

$w'+y=\sin(x)$

$y'-z=e^x$

$z'+w+y=1$

where $w(0)=0$ and $z(0)=y(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are w, y and z functions of x?

If so, hint:

$w'' + y' = \cos x$ from eq 1

$\to w'' + e^x + z = \cos x$

$\to w''' + e^x + z' = -\sin x$

$\to w''' + e^x + (1-w-y) = -\sin x$

$\to w''' - w = - \sin x - e^x - 1 + y$

$\to w''' - w = - \sin x - e^x - 1 + (\sin(x) - w')$

$\to w''' + w' - w = - \sin x - e^x - 1 + \sin(x)$

$\to w''' + w' - w =- e^x - 1$

Can you apply Laplace transform now?

---

Apply Laplace to get:

$s^3 F(s) - s^2 w(0) - s' w'(0) - s^0 w''(0) + s' F(s) - s^0 w(0) - F(s) = -L(e^x) - L(1)$ (I think. Haven't done Laplace in awhile)

[Get $L(e^x)$](http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/laplace/lt/lt.html).

[Get L(1)](http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/laplace/lt/lt.html).

Solve for F(s) and then:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IVPWithLaplace.aspx

Comment: I can apply laplace now but i don't have w'(0) and w''(0)

Comment: w'(0) = - y(0) + sin(0)

Comment: $w''(0) = cos (0) - y'(0)$, where $y'(0) = z(0) + e^0$

Comment: Ok , and now i can apply the same for y and z , right?

Comment: Oh right that. Well, once you get w, you can get y with the first equation. With y, you can get z with the second equation.

Comment: I have got : L(w) (s^3+s-1)=....

Comment: I haven't done Laplace in awhile. Anyway, I think it's $s^3 F(s) - s^2 w(0) - s' w'(0) - s^0 w''(0) + s' F(s) - s^0 w(0) - F(s) = -L(e^x) - L(1)$

Comment: And what to do with (s^3+s-1) ? That's what i am asking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23779/discussion-between-bclc-and-malak-diab).

Comment: L{w}(s^3+s-1)=(-1/s-1)-(1/s)-s-1

Comment: This what i exactly get

Comment: What is L{w} ? Specifically, what is L{w}(s^3+s-1) ? I think you're supposed to end up with (F(s))(something) = whatever you get when you simplify $-L(e^x) - L(1)$

Comment: Okay. Solve for F(s). Also did you mean maybe $\frac{-1}{s-1}$ instead of -1/s-1?

Comment: I mean isolate it. F(s) = ((-1/s-1)-(1/s)-s-1)/((s^3+s-1)), assuming you are correct with L{w}(s^3+s-1)=(-1/s-1)-(1/s)-s-1 and L{w} = F(s)

Comment: Ok, but finding inverse laplace for this form is not clear

Comment: Malak, it's not supposed to be intuitive. You'll have to recognize patterns. Try a partial fraction decomposition maybe.

Comment: Again, I don't think L{w}(s^3+s-1)=(-1/s-1)-(1/s)-s-1 is right http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282334/laplace-transform-of-fx